# Static variable does not return what's expected in Java

Tags: java, static

I have a class that holds a static variable but does not return what I expected.

```
public class helper {
    public static int a = 5;
}
```

This class reaches the static variable and changes it.

```
public class alistirma {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(helper.a);
        helper.a += 3;
        System.out.println(helper.a);
    }   
}
```

However I expected this code to return 8, but it returns 5.

```
public class dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(helper.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `main` are you running?

Comment: The value will not persist across executions of the same program. I think that is your misunderstanding.

Comment: If various programs reference the same static variable, it doesnt mean that they magically share a variable, each program allocates its own static variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two public static void Main(String args[]){} functions, so remove one of them. Maybe change your alistirma class to this:

```
public class alistirma {
public static void changeValue{
    System.out.println(helper.a);
    helper.a += 3;
    System.out.println(helper.a);
}
```

}

And then, make your dummy class call alistrima's changeValue method.

```
public class dummy {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    alistirma.changeValue();
    //System.out.println(helper.a); don't need this now
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Each time you run the program everything starts over from scratch. Unless you call the main method in *alistirma* before the main method in *dummy* you will just get the initial value for *helper.a*.